# OpenGL Vertex Array sphere stray vertex

Tags: c++, opengl

I've been trying to code a sphere in opengl using various code snippets online, but after running the code theres a stray vertex and I'm not sure where my code has missed it:

[image]

CODE:

```
    float Lats = 1/(float)(longitude-1);
    float Longs = 1/(float)(latitude-1);

    int r,s;

    vector<GLfloat> vertices;
    vector<GLfloat> normals;
    vector<GLfloat> texcoords;
    vector<GLushort> indices;

    for(r = 0; r < longitude; r++)
    {
        for(s = 0; s < latitude; s++)
        {
            float const x = cos(2*M_PI * s * Longs) * sin( M_PI * r * Lats );
            float const y = sin( -M_PI_2 + M_PI * r * Lats );
            float const z = sin(2*M_PI * s * Longs) * sin( M_PI * r * Lats );

            vertices.push_back(x * getR());
            vertices.push_back(y * getR());
            vertices.push_back(z * getR());

            normals.push_back(x);
            normals.push_back(y);
            normals.push_back(z);

            texcoords.push_back(s*Lats);
            texcoords.push_back(r*Longs);
        }
    }

    for(r = 0; r < longitude; r++) 
    {
        for(s = 0; s < latitude; s++)
        {
            indices.push_back(r * latitude + s);
            indices.push_back(r * latitude + (s+1));
            indices.push_back((r+1) * latitude + (s+1));
            indices.push_back((r+1) * latitude + s);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Could we see the complete rendering code? Maybe when you draw the lines (I assume you're using glBegin/glEnd primitives?), the first point is not the first vertex of your defined circle, but the (0,0,0) vertex, for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm using vertex arrays drawing with GL_QUADS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing,

```
float Lats = 1/(float)(longitude-1);
float Longs = 1/(float)(latitude-1);
```

<strike>The north pole of the sphere is causing a division by 0.</strike>

**Updated**

After looking at your code again I think the issue may be a bit more subtle.

You are assuming

```
2*M_PI/* double */ * (latitude - 1)/*int*/  * 1/(float)(latitude - 1)/*float*/ == 2*M_PI
```

Because of floating point issues that may not be true. This applies to all the other expressions in sin() & cos()

Probably you are dealing with a loss of precision.

Since it is deterministic you could even fix it up manually at the end. This still applies though.

<strike>Interestingly your Front-face, back-face color coding clearly indicates the problem, There is a "knot" at the top</strike>

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if thats the problem as longitude/latitude is never 1 so lats and longs is never 1/0, the sphere had a texture on it which explains the colour. I can post another picture without a texture if  you prefer?

Comment: @Split Yes, please post the plain image.

Comment: @Split Here's 2 tests to diagnose the problem. 1.> Is the odd point the origin? Render something there to check. If it is then most likely the above applies. 2.> When you are rendering are you leaving the last rectangle incomplete? Check this by manually substituting in the indices loops, `s = latitude - 1`, & r = `longitude -1`

Comment: I've narrowed it down, theres a square made up of vertex 60,72,71,60, There isnt a vertex 72 so thats the problem. If I change the loops so they are less than or equal to, the problem is still there. Whilst looking through the vertice data, theres a positions which are e-00x .. for example vertex [269] is -1.1006487e-006, could this be the problem?